# Is there a way to get a nested JSON object using react native?

Tags: json, react-native

My JSON file can be found using [this](https://www.vaccinespotter.org/api/v0/states/AL.json) link. The object "features" have a nested object called "properties", where I want to access the data from that object. I've tried to use the `useEffect()` hook from React and implemented that in the code below. I tried to get the "properties" sub object by implementing the following code: `data.features.properties`, but that returns undefined. What code am I implemented wrong or what logic is incorrect?

```
useEffect(() => {

fetch('https://www.vaccinespotter.org/api/v0/states/' + stateAbb + '.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    setData(json);
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, [stateAbb]);
```

stateAbb is the state abbreviation for the state that the user selects in a text input on a different screen. propData seems to store the "features" object as I have used the `alert()` function and `typeof()` to determine that propData is an object.

I've tried to JSON.parse() and implemented some other StackOverflow answers, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520847/using-map-to-access-nested-json-in-react-native) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238882/react-state-nested-object-returns-undefined). The effect still remains the same. `data.features` works as an object but `data.features.properties` returns undefined.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `features` is an array.

Comment: Thanks! So then how can I get the object from within that array?

Comment: There is no __the__ object, there are many objects in that array.

Answer (score 0):

React hooks doesn't allow async await in `useEffect` so you can create new function like this

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  fetchData()
},[])

const fetchData = async ()=>{
  try{
    const response = await  fetch('https://www.vaccinespotter.org/api/v0/states/' + stateAbb + '.json')
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log(json); // your data is here!
  }catch(err){
   console.log(err)
  }
}
```